# Xamarin.iOS:How to change the size of image in toolbar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with Xamarin.iOS .Now I have to download image from service as the toolbaritem.However,the image beyond the display area .

[image]

I know that it is due to the size of image too large.But I can't set the `contentmode` of items like  in `UIImageView`.So any suggestion(Or is it possible)?

Comment: How do you set this image on the toolbar item?

Comment: It works fine when I use the same iamge in Assert

Comment: Please show the code you use to actually set the image on the toolbar item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale the size of image after you  download it from service.Refer to the following code

```
/*
   sourceImage:the iamge that you download
   newSize the size you want ( for example 25*25)
*/
public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage,CGSize newSize)
{

  if(UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale==2.0) //@2x iPhone 6 7 8 
    {
      UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 2.0f);
    }


  else if(UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 3.0) //@3x iPhone 6p 7p 8p...
    {
      UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 3.0f);
    }

  else
    {
     UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(newSize);
    }

   sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

   UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

   return newImage;

  }
```